# how to add third party .net dll in xamarin whose source code is not known

Tags: xamarin

I want to add .net dll to xamarin but I don't have the source code for that dll...So I can't make changes to the dll code and compile on xamarin. That is a third party dll which just needs to be added in my application that I am making in xamarin. I can't make changes to the code of third party dll. Whenever I had to make an application I used to refer that dll in my dot net code. But now I want to make same application on xamarin.But how can I refer to dll. Plz suggest some way. Is there any way to port our dll on some other platform. Plz suggest some way with easy explanation

Comment: Plz show me the codez! Ok first up are you using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio? tag needed. Second, why dont you just overload the methods and/or provide your own implementation? Third, if its a 3rd party DLL do you have the rights to modify their code? Fourth, have you tried Reflector or ILSpy to see the code in the 3rd party DLL? You need to provide a lot more information. Please read the [FAQ]'s and update your question.

Comment: Plz answer my question plzzz

Comment: scan.xamarin.com will tell you how compatiable a dll is with each Xamarin platform.  If you don't have source and it's not compatible then you will have to find an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

The .net dll in question probably has references that do not exist on Xamarin platform. Thus without sources you can't do anything. And even if you had sources you probably couldn't do anything easily. That's pretty much it given the details.

Comment: I hope OP can see from this answer without further information (ie the 4 questions I asked) that we cant provide any help.

Comment: Our organisation provides some devices and to work with those devices we need to add certain .net dlls so that application can  communicate with device..So that means we can't build any application with our devices on xamarin??????

Comment: Implement that functionality on server or ask the manufacturer of DLL to support Xamarin.